# Spring Kafka AckOnError

Tags: spring-kafka

I have configured SeekToErrorHandler with DeadLetterPublisheingRecoverer

```
 ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(primaryConsumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(this.kafkaConfigProperties.getConsumerConcurrency());
    factory.setAutoStartup(true);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.RECORD);               
    factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublisheingRecoverer(kafkaTemplate()),3));
```

When an exception is thrown from listener (or validator), after three retries, the message gets published to the dead letter.

The issue here is next time when restart my spring boot application (or listener container), same message gets again delivered to the listener and goes through the entire sequence and finally lands on dead letter. Is there any way to avoid this?

I have disabled auto commit and have set AckOnError(false) and AckMode(AckMode.RECORD);

In SeekToErrorHandler, I could find that the logic around SeekToUtil which throws exception until configured number of iterations gets completed and finally calling the accept method of the BiConsumer (deadletter publishing). So the container should commit the record on the final step (on publishing to dead letter) right? I have also gone through the comment on ackOnError(boolean) method in org.springframework.kafka.listener.ContainerProperties

When setAckOnError(true), I could find correct behavior with three retries and finally invoking dead letter publisher. The message not getting re-delivered when listener container restarted

Spring kafka version is 2.2.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2.3 we added `ackAfterHandle`; with the default being true for the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`.

```
@Override
public boolean isAckAfterHandle() {
    return this.ackAfterHandle;
}

/**
 * Set to false to tell the container to NOT commit the offset for a recovered record.
 * @param ackAfterHandle false to suppress committing the offset.
 * @since 2.3.2
 */
public void setAckAfterHandle(boolean ackAfterHandle) {
    this.ackAfterHandle = ackAfterHandle;
}
```

In 2.4 it defaults to true for all error handlers.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1273

Comment: Thanks Gary Russell. But how multiple retry happens when setAckOnError(true) in 2.2.6. Even if SeeToErrorHandler throws exception during first retry, container could commit the offset just after delivering record first time itself, right?

Comment: `ackOnError`, when true, means the offset is committed before the error handler is called; since the STCEH re-seeks the failed record (when retries are not exhausted) the commit is effectively un-done; the commit remains in place after retries are exhausted. The problem with that approach is there is a small timing window between the commit and the seek which could (rarely) cause the record to be lost. Hence the new property `ackAfterHandle`.

Comment: Got it @Gary Russel. Thanks

Comment: As long as I use v2.2.6, I think, better approach could be to use AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE and call setCommitRecovered() of STCEH for failure scenarios and call acknowledgment. acknowledge() for success scenarios from with in the listener, @Gary Russell

Comment: Yes, that is correct; it will eliminate the timing problem with `ackOnError`. However, the current 2.2.x version is 2.2.12. 2.2.6 is nearly a year old; you should try to keep up to date, at least within the minor version you are using, if you can't move to a new minor version. The current version is 2.4.2.

Comment: @GaryRussell so how to substitute in v2.7.6 the obsolete: `containerFactory.containerProperties.isAckOnError = false` ?

Comment: It is no longer relevant; read the answer; it is replaced by `isAckAfterHandle()` on the error handler (the commit is only performed if the error handler "handles" the error. If there is something that is not clear, ask a new question showing code/config and what you don't understand. `ackOnError` had a race condition that could (rarely) cause message loss.