# setAckOnError() method for Spring kafka 2.7.8

Tags: spring-kafka

while upgrading our spring kafka to 2.7.8, we are getting error in the setAckOnError(false) method as it has been deprecated now. Is there any way now to set the acknowledgement for the errors to false? Any other methods that can help me to set it as false for errors acknowledgement?
P.S: I am new to Kafka, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That property was found to have a (very small) timing hole in that a record could be ack'd before the error handler handles it; if the app dies at that time, the record could be "lost".

It was replaced by a new feature in the error handlers `ackAfterHandle`; which is true by default - i.e. the record's offset is only committed if the error handler "handles" the error.

Records are now never ack'd if the error handler (such as the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`) throws an exception (after it repositions the partitions).

There is no extra configuration needed any more.

See [Spring Kafka AckOnError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60284840/spring-kafka-ackonerror/60286089#60286089) for more details.